# Display block on mobile screens

Tags: html, css

Check this website on mobile you'll understand what I'm trying to do. [This is my website](http://23.22)

Notice how on the index  on wix, the becomes `display: block` on mobile. I mean `your success and the two other boxes`.

I tried to do the same, it worked awfully on desktop when resizing the browser, but on mobile it didn't.

I have `index_whitebox` and `index_whitebox_2` and `index_whitebox_3`

It goes like this:

CSS

```
.index_whitebox{
    min-height: 380px;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Same CSS with slight difference in the margin for the other two boxes.
As for media query:

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .index_whitebox{
        min-height: 0;
        width: 90%;
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        margin-left: auto
        margin: auto;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        display: block;
    }  

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="whitebox_wrapper">
    <div class="index_whitebox">
        <div class="index_title">
            title
        </div>
        <div class="index_image">
        </div>
        <div class="index_article">
            <div class="index_first_cell_text_wrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="index_nav_container">
            <a href="contact.html" class="navButton_2">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and same html for the other boxes.

Comment: According to your page source you are using Bootstrap as your framework.  That being the case, why would you not make use of their Grid and Responsive Utilities, as any combination of the two would provide you a class-only solution instead of having to write custom media queries.

Comment: do you want to create the same or trying to make it responsive?

Comment: @RobertC I just added bootstrap to see if I can solve the issue with it, but I haven't try it and I'm afraid I may have to redesign the entire thing

Comment: @HeadInCloud I'm trying to do the same thing, if there's an alternative responsive solution that might produce the same result then it's ok

Comment: Abraham Lincoln did not state the quote you claim on your site. [reference](http://quoteinvestigator.com/tag/abraham-lincoln/). And [Other reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dx8siugG440)

Comment: You should put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head></head>` area of your site for correct mobile scaling.

Comment: @user3528269 thank you! it worked, still rubbish but at least I see something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .header{min-width:100%;}
    #banner{min-width:100% !important;}
    .whitebox_wrapper{min-width:100%;}
    .index_wrapper{width:100%;}
}
```

it might help you

Comment: thank you! it worked, still rubbish but at least I see something

Comment: would you help answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100071/using-a-toggle-navigation-on-mobile-screens im having hard time aligning the toggle button and displaying it correctly